# Configure Gitlab to run on different port

Tags: linux, nginx, centos, gitlab, gitlab-7

So I tried many different ways of doing this but I can't seem to get it to work. I have the latest gitlab downloaded on CentOS 7. I changed the `external_url` on `etc/gitlab'gitlab.rb` to `http://domain.com:987`. No luck.

Then I changed the nginx setting `listen_port` to `987` and still no luck. But port 80 seem to be working fine. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Can someone please help?

Comment: Does this help http://serverfault.com/q/585528/162751?

Comment: @EtanReisner I have tried everything I can find with google. And that is exactly what I did if you read my question properly

Comment: You didn't indicate that you restarted or reconfigured anything. Just that you edited the files. That's an **incredibly** common mistake just about everywhere. So instead of saying "are you sure you restarted" (since I don't know the correct way to do that for gitlab) I pointed you at a set of directions that looked reasonable. Are you sure you are talking to the service you believe you are talking to? Is there a (reverse?) proxy in front of the service? Are you talking to the right host? What does `ss -tlnp` (as root) list as listening on what ports?

Comment: @EtanReisner here is the result of `ss -tlnp` http://i.imgur.com/Qezpz1s.png . I am not sure about the other questions you asked. I point my web browser to <my_domain>.com:987 and it says "can't connect to server". And yes I did use gitlab-tcl reconfigure everytime i made a change to gitlab.rb

Comment: If that's the entire output then you aren't connecting to where you think you are connecting. Because nothing in there is listening on port 80. And nginx *is* listening on port 987. So back to are you sure you are connecting to the machine you think you are? Does `host <your_domain>` return the result you expect from that machine and from the machine your are trying to connect from (`nslookup <you_domain>` for Windows)? If you try to connect via IP address does it work?

Comment: Yes I did change the port to 80 and it works so I know I am connecting to the correct macine

Comment: Ok I figured it out. it was the firewall. I had to open up the port on firewall

Comment: @balbzr: In this case, either post that as an answer, vote to close your question, or delete your question altogether, but don't hide that detail in a comment.